# I want pagination url with out href url link in codeiginter

Tags: codeigniter

I have  use codeiginter pagination functionality. But I want pagination url with out href url link in codeiginter. how can possible please help?

Comment: This is currently not possible, You might try cleaning the links or creating them manually (there's an open issue regarding this And I hope it will be available soon).

Answer (score 0):

you can play with Pagination library , create your own library like so

```
application/libraries/Pagination.php
```

and copy the content of CI native pagination library file into the file that you just created from

```
system/libraries/Pagination.php
```

so this way you don't touch core files

then search for "here we go..." in my version it is on line 225

underneath you can see how those links are rendered and you can change them as you wish

```
// And here we go...
$output = '';

// Render the "First" link
if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links + 1))
{
    $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;
    $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
}
.... etc
```

you can read more about Replacing and extending Native Libraries with Your Versions here [http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.htmll](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html)

hope that helps!

Comment: DRY! If you need some/all code from existing system library (Pagination.php in this case), Make `APPPATH . '/libraries/MY_Pagination.php'` that extends Pagination class as pointed in [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries).

Comment: yes as I said in the answer , you can read more about Replacing / Extending Native libraries, it depends what the OP whats to do with his links :) , the doc talks about both senarios